# Stacked Area Chart in Plot.ly and R

Tags: r, plotly, stacked-area-chart

Plot.ly has a [tutorial](https://plot.ly/python/filled-area-plots/#stacked-area-chart-with-original-values) on this for Python:

```
# Add original data
x=['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall']

y0_org=[40, 80, 30, 10]
y1_org=[20, 10, 10, 10]
y2_org=[40, 10, 60, 80]

# Add data to create cumulative stacked values
y0_stck=y0_org
y1_stck=[y0+y1 for y0, y1 in zip(y0_org, y1_org)]
y2_stck=[y0+y1+y2 for y0, y1, y2 in zip(y0_org, y1_org, y2_org)]
```

R doesn't seem to have any similar tutorial. I tried to play with the filled area plot tutorial for R, but failed to build a stacked plot.

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c(0, 2, 3, 5), fill = "tozeroy")
add_trace(p, x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c(3, 5, 1, 7), fill = "tonexty")
```

How can I replicate the code above in R/ Plot.ly to create a stacked area chart? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I got it:

```
library(plotly)

x <- c('Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall')
y0 <- c(40, 80, 30, 10)
y1 <- c(20, 10, 10, 10)
y2 <- c(40, 10, 60, 80)

y1 <- y0 + y1
y2 <- y1 + y2

p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_area(aes(x, y2, fill = 'green')) +
  geom_area(aes(x, y1, fill = 'blue')) +
  geom_area(aes(x, y0, fill = 'red'))

ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @teja-k! The code works perfectly. However, my dataset is not as simple - some of the y0 values can be higher than y2 or y1 values are higher than y2. I'm adding the screenshot of the result I'm getting to the original post.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just figured it out myself too :) You have to create stacked variables, start with the biggest one and move to the one with the smallest value: p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_area(aes(x, y2+y1+y0, fill = 'blue'))+
  geom_area(aes(x, y1+y0, fill = 'red'))+
  geom_area(aes(x, y0, fill = 'green'))

  ggplotly(p)