# Overlapping of colors with Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am working with Plotly. My idea is to make plot with different colors, where for each variable I can see different color. Below you can see my data and my code.

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(plotly)
    
    # Sample data frame (replace this with your actual dataset)
    data <-

 data.frame(
  Column1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  Column2 = c(5, 6, 7, 8),
  Column3 = c(9, 10, 11, 12),
  Column4 = c(13, 14, 15, 16)
)

# Calculate cumulative sums for each column
data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    Cumulative_Column1 = cumsum(Column1),
    Cumulative_Column2 = cumsum(Column2),
    Cumulative_Column3 = cumsum(Column3),
    Cumulative_Column4 = cumsum(Column4))
```

Now I am trying to make plot of this data with Plotly.

```
Chart1 <- plot_ly(
  data,
  x = ~Column1,
  y = ~Cumulative_Column1,
  name = 'Cumulative_Column1',
  type = 'scatter',
  mode = 'lines',
  fill = 'tozeroy'
) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Column1, y = ~Cumulative_Column2 , name = 'Cumulative_Column2') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Column1, y = ~Cumulative_Column3 , name = 'Cumulative_Column3') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Column1, y = ~Cumulative_Column4 , name = 'Cumulative_Column4') %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      title = ' ',
      tickmode = 'linear',
      dtick = 1  # Set the interval to 1 for integer years
    ),
    yaxis = list(title = ''),
    title = "",
    annotations = list(
      x = 0,
      y = -0.09,
      title = " ",
      text = "Source: ",
      showarrow = F,
      xref = 'paper',
      yref = 'paper'
    )
  )
```

Unfortunately this data give me a chart as chart below with mixed (overlapping) colors, instead to have colors as showed in the legend of the Chart.

[image]

Can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: `fill = 'tozeroy'` --> `fill = 'tonexty'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacked area chart using Plotly and R without ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905565/stacked-area-chart-using-plotly-and-r-without-ggplot)